# counting words containing character

Tags: c, char, character

```
#include <stdio.h>
int hledejznak(x)
{
    int c;
    int pocitadlo=0;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        if(x==c){
            pocitadlo++;
            while((c=getchar())!=32)
            {
                printf("%d\n",c);
            };
        };
    };

    return pocitadlo;
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int znak=*argv[1];
    printf("answer is %d",hledejznak(znak));
    return 0;
}
```

Hi people, I need to count words containing character specified as argument at terminal 
example: echo 'hello babe' | ./main e

Answer is 2

....because there are two words containing letter "e"
My code doesn't work, can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: Doesn't work in what way?  And what's with all of the whitespace?

Comment: the only thing it makes is writing out:-1-1-1-1-1-1-1.....

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't nest your loops; keep the outer one that processes each character read
2. Have a boolean variable initalized to false & set to true whenever you see the desired character.
3. Whenever a word ends, increment your counter if the flag is true.  Either way, set the flag to false (to get ready for the next word).  (Note that the last word may NOT end with a space.)
4. Only when you're processed all of the input should you print the value of the counter.

Comment: can you, please, write that code as you described? sorry for my english...

Comment: @user1477988 - Why should this person write code for you? Are you going to pay this person?!